# HTML helper Action Link

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, html-helper, actionlink

I am getting below compilation error :
`Compiler Error Message: CS1929: 'HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<Department>>' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLink' and the best extension method overload 'AjaxExtensions.ActionLink(AjaxHelper, string, string, object, AjaxOptions, object)' requires a receiver of type 'AjaxHelper'`

But unable to find what I am missing

Below is  my  Index.cshtml file:

```
@using HotelBookingApp.Models;

@model IEnumerable<Department>

<div style="font-family:Arial">
    @{
                    ViewBag.Title = "Departments List";
    }

    <h2>Departments List</h2>
    <ul>
        @foreach (Department department in @Model)
        {
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink(department.Name,"Index","Employee",
 new { departmentId = department.DeptId }, null)
        </li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your code and it seems that it's working (fresh MVC project), so the problem must be in the configuration. Please check if your Web.config file (inside Views directory) contains this line (configuration.system.web.webPages.razor.pages.namespaces node):

```xml
<add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
```

You can also try to add `@using System.Web.Mvc.Html` at the top of your view file - error message suggest that namespace which contains `Html.ActionLink` isn't included.

Comment: Have you modified configuration files, or put view file somewhere outside of the Views directory? Updating packages can also generate similar problems.

Comment: Got the issue. I was using the wrong property, department.Name  instead of department.DeptName

Comment: Ah, right, error messages are very misleading in this situation.